# Botão Voltar - Nível acima ou Página anterior

Tags: html

Bom dia, sei que a pergunta parece estranha e meio óbvia, mas tenho tido essa dúvida a um tempo...

Digamos que tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
Home
Clientes
---Lista
------Editar
---Cadastro
```

Se o camarada estiver no "Editar", ao clicar no meu botão "voltar", por padrão ele ele vai para "Lista"... Mas se ele tiver entrado na página "Editar" diretamente pelo URL por exemplo? O "location back" não vai funcionar certo? Devo então definir meu botão "Voltar" já com o link do nível superior (Lista)?

Qual seria a forma correta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha opinião: Caso você possua esse botão de voltar em sua página, isso realmente ficará a seu critério. O botão voltar do navegador já irá fazer a função de voltar, o que eu não te impede de ter a mesma função na sua página, por questão de design ou navegação. Mas no seu caso você pode sim fazer com o que o usuário "retorne" para a página desejada.

Estretanto isso pode criar um problema de lógica em alguns outros casos, por exemplo:

- Supondo que a página A é encaminhada para página C.
- Foi criado uma página B que também será encaminhada para página C.
- No botão de voltar da tela C, teria que direcionar para página A ou página B de acordo de onde o usuário veio.

Mas se ele acessar a página C diretamente pela URL, o que fazer?

Entendeu, aí que teremos que pensar cuidadosamente, você pode deixar dois links paras duas páginas, ou deixar para uma página anterior as duas, em uma lógica hierárquica como a da sua pergunta. Isso será maleável de acordo com a estrutura geral de seu site, e como já disse ficará a seu critério.

Comment: Show, entendi. Vou ver essa questão da lógica aqui, pois acredito que definir a página diretamente será melhor. Fiz um teste aqui e se o usuário atualiza as informações de um cliente e clica no botão Voltar ele acaba voltando pra mesma tela de edição que estava e isso já vai gerar um desconforto e choradeira rs.

Answer (score 0):

Pense no conceito de "voltar", que está relacionada à um histórico.

Se a página foi acessada de forma direta, a página anterior à ela seria o comportamento "correto", mas nada impede de você forçar sua aplicação à voltar para o nível acima, independente de onde o usuário veio.